# solve the wav2lip train arguments will result in an error?

Tags: python

/content/Wav2Lip/audio.py:100: FutureWarning: Pass sr=16000, n_fft=800 as keyword args. From version 0.10 passing these as positional arguments will result in an error
return librosa.filters.mel(hp.sample_rate, hp.n_fft, n_mels=hp.num_mels,

I am training data in the Colab